# RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding decryption in PHP 7.2

Tags: php, rsa, public-key-encryption, phpseclib, php-7.2

I've been trying to get this to work since this morning, but I'm stuck at this thing for hours now.
This is my Public Key : https://pastebin.com/EBszJhSi
I have a string that I need to encrypt.

String = "Hello"

This is my code below...

```
function RSAEncryption($text)
{

    $encrypted = 'hey';
    $publicKey = "file:/".PUBLIC_KEY;
    $plaintext = "Hello";
    $pubkey = openssl_pkey_get_public(file_get_contents(PUBLIC_KEY));
    openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, re($publicKey), OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING);
    echo $encrypted;   //encrypted string
    return $encrypted;
}
```

This returns nothing. It's pure blank.

```
var_dump(openssl_public_encrypt($plaintext, $encrypted, re($publicKey), OPENSSL_PKCS1_PADDING));
```

This returns "false". I've tried multiple libraries like phpseclib as well and that has another issue. I've tried both the versions of phpseclib, 1.0 and 2.0. The issue with phpseclib was that the files and some variables were missing, even though I downloaded from official sources.

Anyways, can someone please help me with this?

EDIT :

The value of `PUBLIC_KEY` is `/location/keys/publickey.pem`.

`re()` function :

```
function re($key_file_path)
{
    $handle = fopen($key_file_path, "r");
    // echo "Key Contents : " . fread($handle, filesize($key_file_path)) . "<br>";
    return nl2br(fread($handle, filesize($key_file_path)));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With phpseclib:

```
$key = '---- BEGIN SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----
Comment: "imported-openssh-key"
AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABJQAAAQEAgsYRVei5nVln0cX9D/x5OcscdO5WCsmyZUEN
dHhfgVD8UklasxcXElKoL0UEer9nvJWMILAU/ZMHbf0O1SaiYbhFmDFyHi/CfwT6
QHD2mu7qLbadXXs0OiGiTUPwZX2Sux2uoxm0ZwfxjSbO85rlJ7Yg0ZjXkRiw+4qT
OQNyYEq4Vt6R/BwIdf5Yt75+7Nzlm5HHi4TPNE63YJJTdazJQ1OWgdZWIZjk4M9K
Zl8x9qNRsKd2GC1G6CGq+L1DOgBbPVWPE7DGUVYJYYF609Iau11LXS6d2FBDUS3S
xna7mtmlZQNEvSRtctuojWfwWI2k1Ac/DW3RJ+M1ccN78dseEw==
---- END SSH2 PUBLIC KEY ----';

$key = preg_replace('#----.*?----#', '', $key);
$key = preg_replace('#Comment: .*#', '', $key);
$key = str_replace(["\r", "\n"], '', $key);

$key = 'ssh-rsa ' . $key;

$rsa = new RSA();
$rsa->loadKey($key);

echo $rsa;
```

Echo'ing out the key is generally a pretty good way to see if the key successfully loaded. If you comment out the `preg_replace`'s, the `str_replace` and the `'ssh-rsa' . $key` bit (ie. if you try to load the key directly) it won't load but if they're in place then it does.

This technique won't work with OpenSSL because the base64-encoded key structure is, ultimately, an SSH formatted key and OpenSSL doesn't support those. phpseclib, in contrast, does but not in the exact same format as your key. phpseclib expects the keys to be in the same format that they would be in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.